# How to restart a blackberry application?

Tags: blackberry, application-restart, rim-5.0

I'm using blackberry SDK5.0 and I want to restart the application programmatically. How to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to restart an application programatically.  Here is an article on it.

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Allow-an-application-to-restart-itself/ta-p/445223

Thanks

Naveen M